# How to deal with "Expression evaluation is not supported" in Debezium?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm trying Debezium with a connection to Oracle for the first time.

I get `Cannot parse column default value '"MYUSER"."ISEQ$$_475890".nextval' to type '2'.  Expression evaluation is not supported. (io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleDefaultValueConverter)`

There are two notable columns in a table I am trying: the first is `INTEGER generated by default on null as identity (start with 90000000)`. This is a generated column, not a default value per se. I wonder if that uses a sequence and a default value under the covers, though strictly speaking it is generated and not a default value. Another column uses a default of `SYSDATE` which is an actual default value, but not a sequence.

Strangely, I don't see anything in [the documentation for the Oracle connector](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/oracle.html) or in general that explains what the default value restrictions are or how I can work around it. Can anyone help?

([Cross-posted](https://debezium.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/302529-users/topic/How.20to.20deal.20with.20.22Expression.20evaluation.20is.20not.20supported.22))

Comment: Had the same issue but for SQL Server connector. It just doesn't seem to support functional defaults and returns nulls instead. Unfortunately, the fields that require functional defaults are non-nullable in my case.  That causes the connector to fail when validating them. Ultimately, you cannot have non-nullable fields set to null by default. But if Debezium can't parse an expression it treats it as null :(